# intellij idea Run/Debug Configurations window is too small to show all options

Tags: intellij-idea, ide

The Run/Debug Configurations window is too small and there is no scroll bar, I can't see the options at the bottom
[the pop up Run/Debug Configurations window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6g0j.jpg)

I can't add pictures yet,so there's only a link to the picture.
My screen is 1366 * 768,the OS is win7 sp1 64bit,the JDK is oracle 1.8,the IDE version is 2018.2.5
By the way, I tried to set the font to a smaller size in Appearance menu,turned out the window will show all the options at the bottom,but the font is too small to read.

Comment: report a bug...

Comment: Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181880. Try expand the dialog to a full screen.

Answer (score 0):

For those has the same problem,it seems to be a bug.
There is a [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-181880#focus=streamItem-27-2580891.0-0) in the youtrack thread that @Andrey posted in the comments,but it involves replacing the IDE's jars,I haven't tried it.